# Cannot map mutableList to string array KMM -> Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am new to swift and I've been trying to map this array of employees to an array of employee names (Strings). What am I doing wrong?

This is a KMM project so the object definitions are written in Kotlin

```
data class Employee( //kotlin
    val id:String,
    val name:String,
    val isHere:Boolean
)

data class Work( //kotlin
    val id:String,
    val name: String,
    var employees: MutableList<Employee>,
    val todoToday: Boolean
)



struct SideworkCardView: View {
    var work : Work
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(work.name.capitalized)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium))
                .foregroundColor( .black )
            Text(
                work.employees.map( { (employee) -> String in
                    employee.name //ERROR HERE
                }).joined(separator: ", ")
            )
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        }        
    }
}
```

Error:
Value of type 'NSArray.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'name'

Comment: Your code compiles and runs just fine if I add a `struct` for `Employee` with the fields you've listed. It seems like this isn't actually your real code (ie it differs in some important way -- like maybe you've defined it as `[Any]` instead of `[Employee]`) or there's some other element here that we aren't seeing.

Comment: you are right I simplified it for a shorter question let me update it with the real code

Comment: You've edited it, but left out the important information -- the definition of `Work` and `Employee`

Comment: What is the data type of "Employees"?  Can you show that?  It seems to think that `work.employees` is a collection of `NSArrays`.

Comment: Where do you define the guy named 'Work'?

Comment: Seems like the important element here is the Kotlin Multiplatform transformation. I don't have any experience with it myself, but it looks like it's mapping it to `NSArray<Any>` instead of `Array<Employee>`. Maybe you have to do a cast or maybe there's a better way to get the multiplatform translation to do the work for you.

Comment: do you think it might have something to do with the mutableArray? perhaps a simple array class might translate better?

Comment: @barryalan2633 seems like it would be worth an experiment

Comment: yeah that did it, it seems like swift does not have a translation in place for mutableList, I changed it to a regular list and it worked. Thank you all for the help I was loosing it. I am not sure what to do here? do I post an answer or one of you can and I accept it? or do I just leave it as is?

Comment: I think you posting an answer and accepting it after 2 days is a great idea.

Comment: It's *possible* that this may also work `(employees as? [Employee] ?? []).map`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason swift does not translate MutableList appropriately and therefore I was getting that error. As a fix I changed it to a regular List on my Work object. Of course I had to update some code that was relying on that list being mutable but nothing that couldn't be done. If anybody has a different fix or more info as to why this happens, please post another answer.

Comment: That's because `MutableList` is an `interface`, generic interface. And you can't have one of those in the intermediate Objective C code. When KMP generates Objective C code it erases all generic types of interfaces and replaces it with `id` type (which is `Any` type). So, only way to pass generic type data via KMP is to use either concrete types or abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple cast is working for me: `let oHours = SerializationUtilsKt.parseAsOpeningHours( hours)  as? [OpeningHoursResponse]`. The key was "as?" rather than "as".

Probably too late for your use case, but something along the lines of

```
if let employees = work.employees as? [Employee] {
   employees.map{...
   }
}
```